# Pyspark - filter dataframe based on nested structs

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's suppose that we have the following dataframe schema

```
root
 |-- AUTHOR_ID: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Books: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- BOOK_ID: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- Chapters: array (nullable = true) 
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- NUMBER_PAGES: integer (nullable = true)
```

- How to find the authors that have books with `NUMBER_PAGES < 100`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your data structure, the `NUMBER_PAGES` for a given `BOOK_ID` is equal to the sum of `NUMBER_PAGES` for each of its chapters.

You can use `aggregate` function to calculate the number of pages for each book then use filter with `exists` function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.filter(
    F.exists(
        "Books",
        lambda x: F.aggregate(x["Chapters"], F.lit(0), lambda a, b: a + b) < F.lit(100)
    )
)
```

---

For Spark <3.1, you need to use `expr` for aggregate and exists functions:

```
df1 = df.filter(    
    F.expr("exists(Book, x -> aggregate(x.Chapters, 0, (a, b) -> a + b) < 100)")
)
```